# System.Web.UI.ScriptManager' does not have a public property named 'Button'

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

i try to show ssrsc reports in asp.net web page and for this i search tutorials and i find tutorials which shows me add script manager ,reportviewer and a button when i add these 3 things in my project in .aspx page and then when i debug my project then it shows me error 
and here i clear that i can not add ajax tool kit reigster assembly in .aspx page for this how i add register assebly for ajax
code

```
<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div align ="center" class="adminform">       
<br /><br />        
        <center>
        <div class="vpb_main_wrapper"  align="center" style="left: inherit"/><br clear="all"/>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">

          <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />

            <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer2" runat="server" Height="261px" 
                Width="476px">
            </rsweb:ReportViewer>
               </asp:ScriptManager> 
    </center>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Error

```
Type 'System.Web.UI.ScriptManager' does not have a public property named 'Button'.

Source Error:


Line 11:             <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
Line 12:             
Line 13:           <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
Line 14: 
Line 15:             <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer2" runat="server" Height="261px"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you put `Button1` and `ReportViewer2` between `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">` and `</asp:ScriptManager>`

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />

    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer2" runat="server" Height="261px" 
            Width="476px">
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

You need to move `Button1` and `ReportViewer2` out of `ScriptManager1`

```
<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div align ="center" class="adminform">       
    <br /><br />        
        <center>
        <div class="vpb_main_wrapper"  align="center" style="left: inherit"/><br clear="all"/>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager> 
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
            <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer2" runat="server" Height="261px" 
                Width="476px">
            </rsweb:ReportViewer>
        </center>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```